# Wrapping All Parameters of a Pytorch Model with A Function

Tags: pytorch

I want to be able to wrap all convolutional parameters (weight and bias) of my PyTorch model with a function e.g. softmax(weight), sigmoid(weight), or alpha*weight, etc. Is there any way of making this function part of the graph using hooks etc.?

For instance: Let say I have a model called net which has trainable parameters from those I am interested in say only in convolutional layers:

```py
for module in net.modules():
   if is_conv_layer(module):
      module.weight # This is the weight I am interested in.
```

So, replacing the value of the weights are easy:

```py
for module in net.modules():
   if is_conv_layer(module):
      module.weight.data = sigmoid(module.weight.data)
```

But, I want to also add sigmoid to the graph so that when backprop is computed, sigmoid is also taken into account.

Comment: Can you include an example, say a toy network and explicitly show how you want to accumulate the parameters to get the desired output?

Comment: Hi, @swag2198. I edited the question to include an example. Let me know if it made the question more clear. Thanks!